# Custom UITextInput implementation not showing multi-stage input suggestions

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikeyboard, uitextinput, uitextinputtraits

I have a custom `UITextInput`-based text editor. It works very well, except for multi-stage input via marked text.

My marked region renders correctly, and marked text is inserted, but the candidate list above the keyboard is blank.

*For example, here is the Japanese (Kana) keyboard showing suggestions on a standard UITextView:*

[image: Default Marked Text]

*And here is my custom editor displaying the same marked text:*

[image]

I have spent several days debugging this issue and have found that the cause is private class `UIKeyboardImpl` returning `NO` for the method `delegateSupportsCorrectionUI`

If I override this method in a category on `UIKeyboardImpl` and return `YES` instead, then multistage input suggestions correctly display for my text editor. However this does not address the underlying cause of the problem (and it's not usable).

I have also looked very closely at Apple's SimpleTextInput sample code. This implements a basic Core Text editor. SimpleTextInput correctly displays multistage input suggestions, however I cannot seem to find a single difference in its implementation of `UITextInput` that causes it to work and mine to break.

(In fact, I am unable to "break" the SimpleTextInput sample's ability to display multi-stage input. Which leads me to think that my focus on the `UITextInput` implementation is the wrong track. And it is something else altogether.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, this is a bit embarrassing. I just now noticed:

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly) UIView *textInputView
```

> **Discussion**
>
> The view that both draws the text and provides a coordinate system for
>   all geometric values in this protocol. (This is typically an instance
>   of the UITextInput-adopting class.) If this property is unimplemented,
>   the first view in the responder chain is selected.

In the documentation.

I had stupidly `@synthesize`'d this property and forgot about it, meaning my UITextInput implementation was returning a `nil` `textInputView`. Simply leaving it unimplemented chooses the first view from the responder chain as described, which provides the text system with the necessary coordinate system to handle auto-correction and multistage input suggestions.

This was after three days of debugging. Now I feel stupid.